# Python tkinter label is flickering while frequently changing displayed image

Tags: python, tkinter, flicker

I currently write a Python program that is used to control a camera in a laboratory. I use tkinter for the GUI and the label that displays the image of the camera (10 FPS, but could be changed) changes to its background color for a fraction of a second while the new image is given to it. The occurance of the flickering does not happen at a set frequency and doesn't change with FPS. It flickers between 3 and 5 times per second. Since the window holds additional GUI elements that have to be accessible during the live stream, I gave the task of refreshing the image to a different thread. There are 3-4 parallel threads for similar tasks running, depending on the state of the program. Down below there are some relevant parts of the code but I can't give you a real MRE since the software for the camera is missing:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

import imagePreprocessing

#Thread function to update the displayed picture according to the FPS defined above
def liveFeedThread():
    global timestamp, labelImageFeed
    while True:
        currentTime = time.perf_counter_ns() #gets current time in nano seconds
        if currentTime - timestamp > 1000000000/fps: #one second/fps -> time between pictures
            image = imagePreprocessing.takeImage() #different module controlling the camera, images are always 640x480
            timestamp = time.perf_counter_ns() #update timestamp before processing picture to ensure timing
            labelImageFeed['image'] = image
        else:
            time.sleep(1E-2)

#Window
window = tk.Tk()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.geometry('640x580') #640x480 for downscaled livestream and 100px height for window components

frameTop = ttk.Frame(window, width=640, height=480)
frameTop.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

labelImageFeed = tk.Label(frameTop, width=640, height=480, bg='black')
labelImageFeed.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

frameBottom = ttk.Frame(window, width=640, height=100, padding=10)
frameBottom.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)
frameBottom.columnconfigure(0, weight=10)
frameBottom.columnconfigure(2, weight=10)
frameBottom.columnconfigure(4, weight=10)
frameBottom.columnconfigure(6, weight=10)
frameBottom.rowconfigure(0, weight=10)
frameBottom.rowconfigure(1, weight=10)
frameBottom.rowconfigure(2, weight=10)
#more code for the GUI elements in the bottom frame is left out of this example

#Live-feed
liveFeed = threading.Thread(target=liveFeedThread, daemon=True)
liveFeed.start()

#more code for different threads is also left out

window.mainloop()
```

I searched for the problem and found someone telling me that tkinter doesn't like threading. Since I can't let all tasks run in the main thread, I hope it is not that. I tried to save the picture in a global variable to ensure it is not only saved in the label. I changed the label to a canvas. I used different FPS. I have a different, older program that uses the same camera but doesn't have any other GUI elements. In this program there are no flickers, so I am pretty sure the problem is about something I don't know about layout managing of tkinter or Python in general since I normally code in Java/C++.

Comment: You cannot write exponent for `time.sleep()`.

Comment: @toyotaSupra: Yes you can. `1E-2` is a valid python number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can solve the problem with "queue" and "threading" modules. Once I modified your code arbitrarily.
First, import the required modules.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

import imagePreprocessing
```

And create gui elements and variables.(convert to class)

```
class CamWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.geometry('640x580')
        self.frameTop = ttk.Frame(self, width=640, height=480)
        self.frameTop.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.labelImageFeed = tk.Label(self.frameTop, width=640, height=480, bg='black')
        self.labelImageFeed.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.frameBottom = ttk.Frame(self, width=640, height=100, padding=10)
        self.frameBottom.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.frameBottom.columnconfigure(0, weight=10)
        self.frameBottom.columnconfigure(2, weight=10)
        self.frameBottom.columnconfigure(4, weight=10)
        self.frameBottom.columnconfigure(6, weight=10)
        self.frameBottom.rowconfigure(0, weight=10)
        self.frameBottom.rowconfigure(1, weight=10)
        self.frameBottom.rowconfigure(2, weight=10)

        self.timestamp = time.perf_counter_ns()
        self.fps = 10
        self.camImage = Queue()
        self.t1 = Thread(target=self.liveFeedThread)
        self.t1.start()
        self.image_update()
```

Here, we determine the initial values ​​of self.timestamp and self.fps, and declare a queue called self.camImage.

And now, we define a function to put the processed image into a queue and a function to update the queued image to the GUI.

```
    def liveFeedThread(self):
        while True:
            currentTime = time.perf_counter_ns()  # gets current time in nano seconds
            if currentTime - self.timestamp > 1000000000 / self.fps:  # one second/fps -> time between pictures
                # image = tk.PhotoImage(file='screenshot.png')
                image = imagePreprocessing.takeImage()  # different module controlling the camera, images are always 640x480
                self.camImage.put(image)
                self.timestamp = time.perf_counter_ns()  # update timestamp before processing picture to ensure timing
            else:
                time.sleep(1E-2)

    def image_update(self):
        try:
            self.labelImageFeed['image'] = self.camImage.get_nowait()
        except:
            pass
        self.after(1, self.image_update)
```

and,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CamWindow()
    app.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure since I haven't seen the imagePreprocessing module, but I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I adjusted some parts of your code to match mine and it solved the problem. However when I used my old code on a different PC, it also worked... But on this one specific laptop, your approach solved the problem :D